# How to completely complie and install mathGL on Mac?

Tags: c++, makefile, hdf, mathgl

Please let me know if there is anyway I can get MathGL working on my computer. If there's any mistake in the following tests, pls kindly let me know.
Thank you.
Ok, I've been struggling this issue for quite a long time. Here's what happens when I try to visualize my results from C/Fortran code
The basic information is:

```
OS: Mac OSX 12.3.1
GCC/GFortran version: 11.3.0
clang version: 13.1.6
```

Case I: Make by default

```
cmake .
cmake .
make install
```

This looks like a minimal installation. The header files are installed to /usr/local/include and the libs are installed to /usr/local/lib.
The default build is able to compile the following code if I run

```
**[compile default]**
g++  src/testMathGL.cpp -o testMathGL -lmgl
```

```
**[testMathGL.cpp]**
#include "mgl2/mgl.h"
 
 int main() {
    mglGraph gr;
    gr.Title("MathGL Demo");
    gr.SetOrigin(0, 0);
    gr.SetRanges(0, 10, -2.5, 2.5);
    gr.FPlot("sin(1.7*2*pi*x) + sin(1.9*2*pi*x)", "r-2");
    gr.Axis();
    gr.Grid();
    gr.WriteFrame("mgl_example.svg");
}
```

I believe the default build is good enough to generate plots. However, the plot is generated and automatically saved on disk. it is not convenient if I am debugging my code(may generate lots of plots and I don't need those). Which might be, I need to tune some parameters to obtain a promising and physically realizable setup. So I want the plot generated and open directly after each single run.

Case II:

In that case, I am trying to run the following code

```
**[testMathGL-fltk]**
#include "mgl2/fltk.h"

int graph(mglGraph *gr) {
    gr->Title("MathGL Demo");
    gr->SetOrigin(0, 0);
    gr->SetRanges(0, 10, -2.5, 2.5);
    gr->FPlot("sin(1.7*2*pi*x) + sin(1.9*2*pi*x)", "r-4");
    gr->Axis();
    gr->Grid();
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    mglFLTK gr(graph, "MathGL demo window title");
    return gr.Run();
}
```

If I try to compile the code with default command

```
**[compile default]**
g++  src/testMathGL.cpp -o testMathGL -lmgl (-lmgl-fltk)
```

The error is straightforward

```
'mgl2/fltk.h' file not found
```

Of course, the default build doesn't contain any graphical libraries. To include those libraries, I tried the prebuilt libraries from MathGL. And I compile as

```
**[compile prebuilt]**
g++  src/testMathGL.cpp -o testMathGL -I/Users/somebody/Downloads/mathgl-8.0-mingw.win64/include/ -L/Users/somebody/Downloads/mathgl-8.0-mingw.win64/lib/-lmgl (-lmgl-fltk)
```

But g++ keeps giving me the errors like

```
unknown type name 'dllimport'
```

As the prebuilt download always has win64 as suffix, I think for Unix-like system, I need to compile it myself.
From the installation instructions from MathGL, I am told it is necessary to enable some keys when configuring the make process. see also http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/Installation.html

```
cmake -D enable-all=on -D enable-all-widgets=on -D enable-all-swig=on .
```

Then it gives a lot of errors stating missing dependencies. I figured most of them, like Qt5, hdf5, glut, fltk, wxWidgets, swig, octave.
Now there are still some missing dependencies I don't know how to resolve. As it shows

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:515 (message):
  HDF4_LIB-NOTFOUND


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:516 (message):
  HDF4MF_LIB-NOTFOUND


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:517 (message):
  HDF4_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:518 (message):
  Couldn't find HDF4 libraries.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:608 (message):
  Couldn't find libHaru or libhpdf.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:612 (message):
  Couldn't find headers of 3d-enabled version of libhpdf.


-- Couldn't find Qt5 WebKitWidgets library. JSON sample disabled.
c-- /usr/local/bin/octave-config x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0 api-v57
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/somebody/Downloads/mathgl-8.0.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/somebody/Downloads/mathgl-8.0.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I am wondering how can I install hdf4? or is hdf4 already replaced by hdf5?

Comment: Obviously you cannot use windows libs etc. on MacOS, so just delete that completely.  But I don't understand why you think you need to build, just to get the header files: didn't you already successfully link?  You said you installed the headers into `/usr/local/include` so does that mean you have the file `/usr/local/include/mgl2/mgl.h`, and if so isn't it enough to add `-I/usr/local/include` to your compile line?

Comment: I do not know or use this package, but there seems to be a port of it... https://ports.macports.org/port/mathgl/

Comment: Thanks, MadScientist. Yes, I can compile and run my code if I only want to generate a plot figure. But if I need to see the plot immediately on screen, it is necessary to compile with header fltk.h and link to library libmgl-fltk.a (rather than mgl.h and libmgl.a), that's why I am building MatGL with fltk.

Comment: Yes, ports seems to be a solution. But installation of ports requires Xcode. That's a massive app and I am not willing to use it. Is hdf4 and hdf5 independent? or hdf5 already provide the necessary compatible libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Emmmmm, I have a tricky solution for my requirement above now. Which is call system applications to display the current plots.

```
#include "mgl2/mgl.h"
#include <iostream>
 
 int main() {
    mglGraph gr;
    gr.Title("MathGL Demo");
    gr.SetOrigin(0, 0);
    gr.SetRanges(0, 10, -2.5, 2.5);
    gr.FPlot("sin(1.7*2*pi*x)", "r-2");
    gr.Axis();
    gr.Grid();
    gr.WriteFrame("mgl_example.svg");
    std::system("open mgl_example.svg -a Gapplin");
}
```

Still looking for solutions to compile MathGL...